# R Filtering Out Rows with missing values

Tags: r

I have a csv file where (in one column) some values are missing, and I want to omit the corresponding rows in the data.file.

I thought that by writing

```
data <- read.csv(file="name.csv",head=TRUE,sep=";", na.strings = "NA")
```

the na.strings = "NA" option replaces missing values with NA, and then I can use

```
cleanData <- na.omit(data) or cleanData <- data[complete.cases(data), ]
```

to filter out the missing parts.

But even after applying the first part, i.e. including the na.strings = "NA" option, the resulting data frame still contains rows with empty entries and not with NA entries.

Does anybody know what went wrong?

Comment: did you try `data[data == ""] <- NA`?

Comment: Oh perfect this works, but I am still curious why na.strings = "NA" does not work. They way I understand the documentation is should handle my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to answer the question you raise in the comments:

I believe you have the purpose of the `na.strings` argument turned around. It doesn't tell `R` how to replace `NA`s.  Rather, it tells `R` which values in the input file *should be treated as* `NA`s.

---

For example, you might run into a data.source that uses `-1` to indicate that the data is missing.  In which case, you would use `na.string='-1'`

if you look at `?read.csv`:

> na.strings
>
> a character vector of strings which are to be interpreted as NA values. Blank fields are also considered to be missing values in logical, integer, numeric and complex fields.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `na.strings` wrongly. To replace empty fields with `NA`, do `data[data == ""] <- NA`.

Answer (score 2):

Try `data.frame.instance <- data.frame.instance[!is.na(data.frame.instance),]` and you should be left with a data.fame without any NAs.